# How do I start in a specified conda environment from a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to create a container for deep learning that contains a list of packages and supports both python 2 and 3. I created a Dockerfile that pulls from `nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-centos7`, then installs Miniconda, then creates python 2 and 3 environments like so:

```
RUN conda env create -f py2_env.yaml
RUN conda env create -f py3_env.yaml
```

The environment files look like so:

```
name: py3
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _tflow_select=2.1.0=gpu
  - lots_of_other_packages
  - pip:
    - affine==2.3.0
    - more_packages_here
prefix: /opt/conda/envs/py3
```

The problem I have is that when I create the container I start in the base environment which doesn't have all my packages, so I start in a python 3 environment but not the one with all my packages. I have to `conda activate py3` to get them. I would like to remove this step. I would like to either install all my packages directly into the base environment or start with the py3 environment activated. I'm tried this by adding this command to my Dockerfile: `RUN /bin/bash -c "conda init bash && source /root/.bashrc && conda activate py3` but it still starts in the base environment.

Comment: Your application wouldn't be able to use both Python 2 and 3.  Create an image that contains only the single version of the language interpreter you need as the "system" Python.  Don't use a virtual environment; Docker provides equivalent isolation.

Comment: I like being in Jupyter Notebooks and being able to create either a python 2 or 3 notebook, and I already got that part to work. I just needed to expose both kernels to jupyter like so: `RUN /bin/bash -c "conda init bash && source /root/.bashrc && conda activate py2 && conda install -y notebook ipykernel && ipython kernel install --user && conda deactivate"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of your docker file

```
CMD ["/bin/sh " "conda init bash && source /root/.bashrc && conda activate py3"]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in my build process: `/bin/sh: /bin/bash : No such file or directory`

Comment: It can't find that either: `/bin/sh: [/bin/sh : No such file or directory`

Comment: I'll try again with the brackets

Comment: Same error without the brackets: `/bin/sh: /bin/sh : No such file or directory`

Comment: docker inspect container-name | grep Platform

Comment: replace your container name

Comment: That container didn't build so I couldn't use that one but I built the container without that line and got `"Platform": "linux"`

Comment: I think you forgot a comma, it should be like that:
CMD ["/bin/sh ", "conda init bash && source /root/.bashrc && conda activate py3"]